# Dealing with php5.4 on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I would like to have php 5.4 on my ubuntu server, even if it's no longer supported.

Then I tried the [ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-oldstable) repository like this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
```

But it adds the repository below

```
[ubuntu@nixmind~]$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php5-oldstable-trusty.list 
    deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu trusty main
    # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu trusty
```

main

and was still giving php5.5.9 with **apt-cache policy**.

```
[ubuntu@nixmind ~]$ apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: 5.4.45-3+donate.sury.org~precise+3
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17
  Version table:
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

I then add the precise repos manually like this :

```
[ubuntu@nixmind ~]$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-php5-oldstable-trusty.list 
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu precise main 
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu trusty main
```

and had this :

```
[ubuntu@nixmind ~]$ apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17
  Version table:
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.45-3+donate.sury.org~precise+3 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

I then installed php5.4 like this :

```
sudo apt-get install php5=5.4.45-3+donate.sury.org~precise+3
```

But php is saying that the version is **5.5.9** while **apt-cache policy** says it's **5.4**

```
[ubuntu@nixmind ~]$ apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: 5.4.45-3+donate.sury.org~precise+3
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17
  Version table:
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.17 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.4.45-3+donate.sury.org~precise+3 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-oldstable/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

and

```
[ubuntu@nixmind ~]$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 (cli) (built: May 19 2016 19:05:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

Then my questions are :

- Why is there a difference between **php -v** and **apt-cache policy**
  outputs?
- Is it just not possible to install php5.4 on ubuntu trusty actually?
- Is a good way to have php5?4 running on ubuntu trusty without this
  ambiguity?

Regards.

Comment: Why 5.4? Do you have a soft spot for unpatched vulnerabilities and reduced performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh). It can install two or more PHP versions side by side.

It works for me on Linux Mint 17.3 (which is based on Ubuntu 14.04) with PHP 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1.

PHP 5.3 doesn't compile though :-(